# setting usage export bucket results in 'unknown collection' error

Tags: google-compute-engine

Need to export the usage information for our project into a storage bucket which has private access and chosen standard policy.
anuradha_natarajan@cloudshell:~ (project-name)$ gcloud beta compute project-info set-usage-bucket --bucket=bucketname
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.project-info.set-usage-bucket) unknown collection for [bucketname]

Was unable to save this configuration thro' console as well as from cli, was thrown the above error. Was expecting the configuration to be saved from console

Answer (score 0):

you're making a syntax error (you're missing gs://). The docs show the correct syntax  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/project-info/set-usage-bucket

```
gcloud config set project $MY_PROJECT
gcloud beta compute project-info set-usage-bucket --bucket gs://$MY_BUCKET
```